# Div tag get down while hover it

Tags: html, css

While I hover Div tag, Another Div tag will appear in front of the prev Div. When i didn't put any words, it works. but when i put h3 tag, the div goes down.

here is the HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <h1 class="head-content">Biscuits</h1>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="list-content">
            <div class="detail-content">
                <h3>Biscuits 1</h3>
                <p>Price: IDR 12000</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="list-content">
            <div class="detail-content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="list-content">
            <div class="detail-content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

here is CSS

```
#content{
        width:50%;
    }
    .line{
        border-top: 5px solid black;
    }
    .list-content{
        display:inline-block;
        width:25%;
        height:200px;
        background-color: black;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .detail-content{
        display: none;
    }
    .list-content:hover .detail-content{
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        height:75%;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    }
```

thank you before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update below css part

```
.list-content:hover .detail-content {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

```css
#content {
  width: 50%;
}

.line {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

.list-content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.detail-content {
  display: none;
}

.list-content:hover .detail-content {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 class="head-content">Biscuits</h1>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="list-content">
      <div class="detail-content">
        <h3>Biscuits 1</h3>
        <p>Price: IDR 12000</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="list-content">
      <div class="detail-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="list-content">
      <div class="detail-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@James Please find following code. I hope you are expecting the same. Just replaced "display:inline-block;" with "float:left;" and took class "list-content" in anchor tag itself.

```css
#content{
        width:50%;
    }
    .line{
        border-top: 5px solid black;
    }
    .list-content{
        float:left;
        width:25%;
        height:200px;
        background-color: black;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    .detail-content{
        display: none;
    }
    .list-content:hover .detail-content{
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        height:75%;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    }
   .clearfix{
   clear:both;
   }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <h1 class="head-content">Biscuits</h1>
    <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="clearfix">  
    <a href="#" class="list-content">
        <div class="detail-content">
                <h3>Biscuits 1</h3>
                <p>Price: IDR 12000</p>
            </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-content">
        <div class="detail-content">

            </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-content">
        
            <div class="detail-content">

            </div>
        
    </a>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `.list-content` items are inline blocks, when you add a text content you have to vertically align them. Add `vertical-align: top` to `.list-content`:

```
.list-content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

And remove the top margin from :

```
h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```css
{
  width: 50%;
}

.line {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

.list-content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}


.detail-content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.list-content:hover .detail-content {
  display: block;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 class="head-content">Biscuits</h1>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="list-content">
      <div class="detail-content">
        <h3>Biscuits 1</h3>
        <p>Price: IDR 12000</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="list-content">
      <div class="detail-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="list-content">
      <div class="detail-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```